# Set few checkboxes selected when page loads (jsf)

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2, checkbox

I am creating web application using JSF 2.0 where I want to set checkboxes to be selected when page loads.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{UserRegistration.rightSelected}" id="myRight">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="add" itemLabel="Add"/>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="delete" itemLabel="Delete" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="edit" itemLabel="Edit" />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

In this case, I want to set, Add and Delete checkbox to be selected by-default. How can I do this?

I tried with,

```
 <body onload="myRight:0:true">
```

Generate HTML content is

```
<td><table id="myRight">
<tr>
     <td>
     <input name="myRight" id="myRight:0" value="add" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />         <label for="myRight:0" class=""> Add</label></td>
     <td>
     <input name="myRight" id="myRight:1" value="delete" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="myRight:1" class=""> Delete</label></td>
     <td>
     <input name="myRight" id="myRight:2" value="edit" type="checkbox" checked="checked" /><label for="myRight:2" class=""> Edit</label></td>
</tr>
```

however it is not working.

Please suggest me how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `rightSelected` is an array init your `rightSelected` as following

```
private String[] rightSelected= {"add","delete"};
```

if `rightSelected` is a List just do

```
rightSelected.add("add");
rightSelected.add("delete");
```

or

```
List<String> rightSelected = Arrays.asList("add", "delete");
```

Comment: `List<String> rightSelected = Arrays.asList("add", "delete");` working... Thanks you always saved me... :) Thanks a ton....